# SQL: case when statement with over (partition by)

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I'm quite new here and have tried various hints from Stackoverflow posts on SQL but haven't been able to solve this one.
I have a table that is result of tables joined, looks like this

Table A

```
cust_id  prod_type

 001         A
 001         A
 002         A
 002         B
 003         A
 003         C
```

I need to apply logic: If for each cust_id  there is at least one value where prod_type is B or C, then return corresponding prod_type value. If for each cust_id all values of prod_type are A, return A.

The final output i am trying to get  is

Table B

```
cust_id     prod_type

 001         A
 002         B
 003         C
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT 
A.cust_id 
,CASE WHEN prod_type in ('B', 'C') THEN prod_type OVER (PARTITION BY A.cust_id)
 ELSE 'A' OVER (PARTITION BY A.cust_id) END AS product 
FROM ([Joined Tables]) AS A
```

and it seems that teradata does not allow to use over(clause) in a case statement: expects 'END' keyword between prod_type and OVER keyword.

Comment: What should happen if a user has both B & C?

Comment: B is sort of historical product which was replaced by C. Old customers are continuing to use B while only new customers can acquire C.

Answer (score 5):

You want to return only one row per customer with the best matching `product_type`?

If there are additional columns:

```
SELECT 
  A.cust_id 
  ,prod_type
  ,...
FROM ([Joined Tables]) AS A
QUALIFY
   ROW_NUMBER()
   OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID
         ORDER BY CASE WHEN prod_type in ('B', 'C') -- best match first
                       THEN 1 
                       ELSE 2
                  END,
                  prod_type) = 1
```

Otherwise @Frisbee's `MAX` will work, but I assume that A/B/C are not your actual product names:

```
SELECT 
  A.cust_id 
  ,COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN prod_type in ('B', 'C') THEN prod_type END) 
           ,MAX(CASE WHEN prod_type not in ('B', 'C') THEN prod_type END))
FROM ([Joined Tables]) AS A
GROUP BY just_id
```

Comment: This works well ! Do i get it right that the purpose of    ' over ()=1 '  is to return all of the rows meeting the condition inside the brackets?  And you are right, ABC are not actual product names but strings

Comment: @Aoy: Yes, this adds a ranking for each customer based on the ORDER BY and returns only the first row...

Answer (score 0):

This query recreates your sample data (table `b`.) Add the row numbers based on specific product order (ranging from C, B to A in the table `a`) then filter on the first row to get the wanted table.

```sql
SELECT
    a.CUST_ID
    , a.PROD_TYPE
FROM (
    SELECT
        b.CUST_ID
        , b.PROD_TYPE
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID ORDER BY DECODE(PROD_TYPE, 'A',3,'B',2,'C',1)) as RN
    FROM (
        /* recreate the exemple table */
        select * from (SELECT '001' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '001' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '002' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '002' CUST_ID, 'B' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '003' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '003' CUST_ID, 'C' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" 
        ) b
    ) a
WHERE RN = 1
order by a.CUST_ID
;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it, and add some explanation as how this answers the question see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

For completness here is an equivalent using the function `first_value` and using the inverse alphabetical order of your products.

Similarly to @Amgalan Bilegjav answer, 'b' is the sample table and 'a' the table with an extra column (finding the first product here).

The code was tested with Teradata version 16.20.53.55

```sql
SELECT
    a.CUST_ID
    , a.PROD_TYPE
FROM (
    SELECT
        b.CUST_ID
        , first_value(b.PROD_TYPE) over (partition by b.CUST_ID order by b.PROD_TYPE desc) as PROD_TYPE
    FROM (
        /* recreate the exemple table */
        select * from (SELECT '001' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '001' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '002' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '002' CUST_ID, 'B' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '003' CUST_ID, 'A' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" UNION all
        select * from (SELECT '003' CUST_ID, 'C' PROD_TYPE) as "DUAL" 
        ) b
    ) a
group by a.CUST_ID, a.PROD_TYPE
order by a.CUST_ID
;
```